# Is the following language recognizable by a visibly pushdown automaton?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, pushdown-automata

Consider the alphabet $\Sigma = \Sigma_c \cup \Sigma_i \cup \Sigma_r$ separated into call, internal, and return letters. Assume that $c \in \Sigma_c, r \in \Sigma_c$, and $a \in \Sigma_i$.
I have a question regarding whether the language:
$L = c^n a c^* a r^n$ is accepted by some Visibly Pushdown Automaton or not. $L$ is obviously context free, and the whole question is whether "not touching the stack" after reading a call symbol is allowed by some definititon of a VPA or not.

Comment: Do you mean $r \in \Sigma_r$?